# debug variables in play framework

Tags: java, debugging, playframework, inspect

How can I **debug** or **inspect variables and classes** in Play framework or simple Java?

In specific:

Which ways are better in application?
*eg. in Ruby on Rails I would do one of the following:*

```
raise myvar.to_yaml        # halts everything for inspect
Rails.logger.debug myvar   # log
puts myvar                 # log
```

And which one would be better in groovy templates?
*eg. in Ruby on Rails:*

```
<%= debug myvar %>
<%= myvar.inspect %>
```

Please note I'm new to Play framework and Java develoment.

Comment: I know only println which returns an unuseful string:
    List<Article> els = query.getResultList().get(0);
    System.out.println(els);
    // [Ljava.lang.Object;@2b2cc880

Comment: Println works for simple things like primatives(int, char, etc), but when called on full objects it uses the object's toString() method.  Your would have it iterate through your list and println each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse, you have an option "Connect JDPA [applicationname].lanuch" to debug. Right click and enable debug.

you can refer the below document for other IDE. It has detailed explanation for debugging.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/ide

Comment: Thanks, in fact it worked. I only had to enable it manually, found here the howto: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWBgl8zKmSY

Comment: Have you executed play eclipsify, this will setup debug option eclipse folder in project.